# How to count rows in a table in an html file C#

Tags: c#, linq, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

When there is a compound table inside an html file how can one count the rows of the parent table.

What I mean by a compound table; a table in which other tables are contained within some of its cells.

Here is my attempt at coding. Note I receive an incorrect values:

```
        String htmlFile = "C:/Temp/Test_13.html";
        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.Load(htmlFile);

        HtmlNodeCollection tables = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table");
        HtmlNodeCollection rows = tables[1].SelectNodes(".//tr");
        Console.WriteLine(" Rows in second (Parent) table: " + rows.Count());
```

Please indicate which namespace is used in your answer.

Here is a representative sample file:

```
<html>
<body>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>Apps</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Offcie Web Apps</td>
</tr>
</table>
<br/>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>Application</td>
<td>Status</td>
<td>Instances</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>PowerPoint</td>
<td>Online</td>
<td>
    <table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Server1</td>
        <td>Online</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Server2</td>
        <td>Disabled</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Word</td>
<td>Online</td>
<td>
    <table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Server1</td>
        <td>Online</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Server2</td>
        <td>Disabled</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you.

Comment: You're using Visual Studio, right?  Examine your `tables` and `rows` collections by hovering over them during a debug; see what's in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly this is what you want.

```
int i = 1;
HtmlNodeCollection tables = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table");
foreach (HtmlNode table in tables)
{
    var tmp = table.ParentNode;
    if (tmp.OriginalName.Contains("td"))
        MessageBox.Show("The parent of table #" + i + " has" + tmp.ParentNode.ParentNode.Elements("tr").Count().ToString() + " rows.");
    i++;
}
```

The MessageBox will pop up 2 times:

```
"The parent of table #3 has 3 rows."
"The parent of table #4 has 3 rows."
```

EDIT (ANSWERING QUESTIONS):

1) I started counter from `int i = 1`. The `var i = 1` will be the same thing, it just automatically replace `var` with `int`.

2) I edited code now you will have same result with me

3) I started counting from 1 so you have table #1, table #2, table #3 and table #4. Your 2 last tables (table #3 and #4) are sub-tables of table #2, table #2 have 3 rows. My above code print only tables that are sub-tables of some table. Can you show me what you want as answer?

EDIT 2:

```
int i = 1;
HtmlNodeCollection tables = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table");
foreach (HtmlNode table in tables)
{
    if (!table.ParentNode.OriginalName.Contains("td")) // If table is not sub-table
        MessageBox.Show("Table #" + i + " have " + table.Elements("tr").Count().ToString() + " rows.");
    i++;
}
```

The MessageBox will pop up 2 times:

```
"The parent of table #1 has 2 rows."
"The parent of table #2 has 3 rows."
```

Comment: I need some assistance with this. The `i` has a squiggly line under it and has the error "The name 'i' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Question 1: I had to initialize the variable 'i' because it had a squiggly line under it. I did it like this: `var i = 0;`. Should I have handled this differently?
Question 2: I also have two messages returned both saying: `The parent of table #0 has3 rows.` How does your code give "#3" & "#4"? Question 3: Why does your code give "3 rows" for both answers? This is wrong. The first table has 2 rows, not 3. Help me get this to return correct answers.

Comment: I edited my code and answered your questions please give a look

Comment: I now see your approach and understand your reply. However what I believe I really need is a solution to query the table directly for its own number of rows rather than working back from the child table and asking about the number of rows of its parent. I need to do it this way because I can't always be certain that the table will have a sub-table. Is there a direct approach to finding the row-count from this perspective without the code being confused when imbedded tables are present? Would you help me with this?

Comment: The result I would like to see from the sample file above would be "Table #2 has 3 rows". In other words I would like the solution to determine the number of rows of the table ignoring the existence of possible sub-tables.

Answer (score 1):

You can push each `<table>` and `<tr>` to the stack and when you encounter `</table>` - pop until the table is popped from the stack.

Comment: It's helpful to have more specific detail. What do you mean by the "stack?" Do you mean a data structure that they would instantiate and parse the HTML, or something else? It doesn't look like they're already using that approach.

Also, please use `<>` around DOM elements, that makes them easier to read, as well as using code formatting around them (and any other code snippets you use). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you try the csQuery nuget package. It's designed to take most of the headaches out of doing things exactly like that. You can use the css selector query syntax, which most web devs are quite familiar with. In this case, you could probably get away with `body > table:nth-of-type(2) > tr` and it will return an array of all the tr's, then just count them, or check the length of the resulting array. Alternatively, `body > table ~ table > tr` would work as well from the sample you gave as would `br + table > tr`